# remove the Carriage return with bash

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk, ldap

I have a Ldif file which I would extract some lines from.

the LDIF is 78 character by line, so whenever there is a line contain more than 78 character it's gonna be devided in two line.

what I want is to count the line which contain 78 characters and if so I will remove the carriage return to rebuild my line again.

so I look for a function or any other way to count if the line is 78 characters and remove the carriage return if so.

example:

```
description: Gestion des acces de la CR 902 sur les environnements Big Data en
  ecriture
distinguishedName: CN=GU_902_A_D5_IC_W,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 902,OU=CAM,DC=LDSCOMPT
 ES
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20180115131643.0Z
```

result I need:

```
description: Gestion des acces de la CR 902 sur les environnements Big Data en ecriture
distinguishedName: CN=GU_902_A_D5_IC_W,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 902,OU=CAM,DC=LDSCOMPTES
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20180115131643.0Z
```

Comment: @dessert That is not problem if there is lines with exactly 78 characters, cause I'll edit the output with other command

Comment: Please post a sample of the file and desired result. Do you really mean carriage return - or is it newline?

Comment: @steeldriver  would you check out update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your samples, it sounds like what you actually want to do is append the following line (removing an additional space character) if the current line is exactly 78 characters long:

```
$ sed '/.\{78\}/{N;s/\n //;}' file.ldif
description: Gestion des acces de la CR 902 sur les environnements Big Data en ecriture
distinguishedName: CN=GU_902_A_D5_IC_W,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 902,OU=CAM,DC=LDSCOMPTES
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20180115131643.0Z
```

A possibly less fragile approach might be to adapt **40. Append a line to the previous if it starts with an equal sign "="** from Peter Krumins' [Sed One-Liners Explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/) to join the *following* line when it *begins* with a space

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n //;ta' -e 'P;D' file.ldif
```

---

NOTE: if your files use DOS/Windows style CRLF line endings, then you will need to replace `\n` in the above expressions by `\r\n` i.e.

```
sed '/.\{78\}/{N;s/\r\n //;}' file.ldif
```

or

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\r\n //;ta' -e 'P;D' file.ldif
```

Comment: @steeldriver I got the same result then what I got with dessert answer

Comment: maybe there is some thing wrong with My file

Comment: @steeldriver maybe this is the issue, I have to check that one

Comment: Yes, it was the file, I've just resolve the problem, it works fine now, thanks

Comment: the both answers work for me... I don't know which one I should choose as the best??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` for that:

```bsh
awk '{substr($0,78,78)==""?a="\n":a="";printf "%s"a,$0}'
```

This command simply checks whether the 78. character of each line is empty and prints the line with or without the line break.

From your example I get that there was also an indention inserted (who does that?!?), to remove these leading extra spaces modify the command to:

```bsh
awk '{gsub(/^ /,"",$0);substr($0,78,78)==""?a="\n":a="";printf "%s"a,$0}'
```

If you have unwanted carriage returns in the file remove them as well:

```bsh
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"",$0);gsub(/^ /,"",$0);substr($0,78,78)==""?a="\n":a="";printf "%s"a,$0}'
```

#### Example run

```bsh
$ <test awk '{gsub(/^ /,"",$0);substr($0,78,78)==""?a="\n":a="";printf "%s"a,$0}'
description: Gestion des acces de la CR 902 sur les environnements Big Data en ecriture
distinguishedName: CN=GU_902_A_D5_IC_W,OU=Groupes,OU=CR 902,OU=CAM,DC=LDSCOMPTES
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20180115131643.0Z
```

Comment: the command put the second line in the begin of the first line not in the end

Comment: I put this: cat brutes.txt |awk '{gsub(/^ /,"",$0);substr($0,78,78)==""?a="\n":a="";printf "%s"a,$0}'

Comment: and this is the result: `ecritureon: Gestion des acces de la CR 902 sur les environnements Big Data en`

Comment: same result of last one

Comment: I think that the problem is the file not the `awk`